# What is it called when words are grouped together by their first letter?

Tags: abbreviations, initialisms, mnemonic

This method is often used in teaching, marketing, management, self-help books, for example:

The 4 T's of success, the 3 D's of determination, etc.

What is this process/method called?

Comment: That's a good question, but I don't think it has an answer. What makes you think there's a dedicated term for this kind of thing? How do you plan on using it?

Comment: Thank you, I work in media and marketing, and we often have to create such content for our clients. I was curious to know what it was called so I can learn more about the methodology (if any) and other similar approaches I can use.

Answer (score 1):

Tyler Schnoebelen in an article entitled **The 3 R’s and 5 W’s of the 4 P’s** on [Corpus Linguistics](https://corplinguistics.wordpress.com/2013/11/06/the-3-rs-and-5-ws-of-the-4-ps/) suggests that these turns of phrase which are alliterative lists are **numeric mnemonics**.

> Lists are a form of semi-structured data. They can be immensely useful in Natural Language Processing. People will often group related items in lists, especially so if they are using **alliteration** to tie list elements together.
>
> I’ll call alliterative lists like “The 4 P’s” **numeric mnemonics** *since they package information for easier retention and recall.*

The article goes on to provide

> an overview of the most popular numeric mnemonics since 1800 ... from the Google Books Ngram Corpus, pulling out all occurrences of “the {number} {letter}’s”.
>
> The counts we’ll be using are not total occurrences of the patterns but distinct books that mention use the construction. I’m going to collapse digits and spelled-out numerals (“3” and “three”), but just so you know, there are about 12 times as many of the spelled-out numbers as digits.

The most popular are

> The 3 R’s: Mostly Reading, (w)Riting and (a)Rithmetic; but also Reduce, Reuse, Recycle and sometimes Respect, Responsibility, and Results (or Rules); Relief, Recovery and Reform; Revenue, cost Reduction, Regulations; and Brazil’s soccer stars Ronaldo, Rivaldo, and Ronaldinho

***Numeric mnemonics*** is used for want of a better name, as it may be confused with the [mnemonic major system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mnemonic_major_system) which

> works by converting numbers into consonant sounds, then into words by adding vowels.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful and a good starting point!